# function call from base adapter to its fragment class

Tags: android

I am having a function in sherlock fragment class. I want to call it from its base adpater class when an item is clicked. My code bellow

In base adapter

```
SherlockFragment obj=new TVgui()
(tvgui)obj.replace_fragment(frag,tag);
```

In  sherlockFragment class

```
 public void replace_fragment(SherlockFragment frag,String tag)
 {
frag_child = getChildFragmentManager();
ft = frag_child.beginTransaction();
    ft.addToBackStack(null)
    .replace(R.id.fragment_container,frag,tag);
    ft.commit();

}
```

Force close with error "Activity destroyed ". pls help

Answer (score 0):

You should use context that you passed to your Adapter instead of creating a new Fragment object. Like this:

```
((TVgui)context).replace_fragment(frag,tag);
```

Comment: but in my adapter I have used activity context not fragment.

Comment: So pass fragment context or add it as an another parameter.